# Get all events from fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, icalendar, fullcalendar-5

i'm trying to access to all the events from a fullcalendar.

All the events are imported with an iCalendar feed :

```
events: {
  url: my_url,
  format: 'ics',
  display: 'background'
}
```

But when I'm using the function `calendar.getEvents()` fullcalendar returns only the visible events from the timeGridWeek view.

I can't access the events of the following weeks.

Is there a way to retrieve all events from fullcalendar ?

Thanks

Comment: No, it only holds in memory what it's needed to fetch for the time periods on display. To get all events, you'd likely need to go directly to the event source (in this case, the ics file)